# Optimizing the calculation of a global maximum

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, list-manipulation, parallelization, gpu

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

n = 4;

A = Table[Table[Indexed[x, {i, j}], {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}];

solns = Maximize[{Det[A], Join[Flatten[Map[{1 <= #, # <= n} &, Flatten[A]]], {Total[Flatten[A]] ==n*Total[Range[1, n]], Product[Flatten[A][[i]], {i, 1, n^2}] == (n!)^n}]}, Flatten[A],Integers][[2]];

MatrixForm[Table[Table[solns[[i*n + j - n]][[2]], {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}]]

Table[Table[solns[[i*n + j - n]][[2]], {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}]
```

I am looking to use this code to maximize the determinant of a $n\times n$ matrix which contains only digits $1$ through $n$ (inclusive), of which each digit must appear exactly $n$ times.

Currently, this code is very slow when $n\ge4$.

How can this Mathematica code be modified to make it tractable when $n\ge4$?

Comment: I believe but I do not think I can prove that the best possible 9x9 matrix for this is any positive-determinant row-column permutation of the following matrix: `RotateRight[Range[9], #] & /@ (Range[9] - 1)`. For the 4x4 case this finds a 4x4 matrix with a determinant of 160, which is an improvement over the existing answer.

Comment: For the n=9 case a determinant of 933,251,220 can be achieved:

```{{9, 4, 1, 5, 6, 8, 3, 2, 7},
 {5, 9, 4, 6, 3, 2, 1, 8, 7},
 {8, 5, 9, 2, 1, 4, 7, 3, 6},
 {4, 3, 7, 9, 8, 1, 5, 2, 6},
 {3, 6, 8, 1, 9, 7, 2, 5, 4},
 {1, 7, 5, 8, 2, 9, 6, 3, 4},
 {6, 8, 2, 4, 7, 3, 9, 5, 1},
 {7, 1, 6, 7, 4, 6, 4, 9, 1},
 {2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 8, 8, 9}}```

Comment: “Each digit appears exactly $n$ times” seems to imply there are $9n$ entries in your $n\times n$ matrix. Did you mean digits 1 through $n$ (for a given $n$ up to 9), by chance?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I did mean 1 through $n$ however I was initially interested in the $n=9$ case when I made the post and must have mixed it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `MaximizeOverPermutations` resource function to find Monte-Carlo stochastic estimates of the maximum (with no guarantee of global maximality). With this method you can get "pretty good" solutions for very large $n$.

As an example, let's do $n=5$:

```
f[L_] := With[{n = Sqrt[Length[L]]}, Det[Partition[Mod[L, n, 1], n]]]

MOP = ResourceFunction["MaximizeOverPermutations"];
M = MOP[f, 25, Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "Iterations" -> 10^5,
                          "AnnealingParameter" -> 1}];
M[[2]]
(*    2196.    *)
```

Show the unique solution(s):

```
Partition[#, 5] & /@ Union[Mod[M[[1]], 5, 1]]
(*    {
        {{3, 1, 5, 4, 2},
         {2, 2, 1, 4, 5},
         {4, 4, 2, 5, 1},
         {1, 5, 4, 2, 3},
         {5, 3, 3, 1, 3}}
      }    *)
```

We can also do $n=9$:

```
M = MOP[f, 81, Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "Iterations" -> 10^5,
                          "AnnealingParameter" -> 1}];
M[[2]]
(*    9.02194*10^8    *)
```

(not quite reached @YusufBashi's maximum yet, need more iterations)

```
Partition[#, 9] & /@ Union[Mod[M[[1]], 9, 1]]
(*    {
        {{6, 7, 2, 4, 7, 1, 5, 9, 5},
         {7, 4, 7, 8, 9, 3, 2, 1, 4},
         {5, 9, 4, 6, 3, 5, 9, 1, 3},
         {1, 4, 2, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 9},
         {3, 1, 8, 7, 3, 2, 9, 6, 6},
         {8, 2, 2, 8, 2, 8, 4, 7, 3},
         {2, 8, 9, 5, 3, 6, 1, 7, 4},
         {9, 5, 6, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 9},
         {5, 3, 6, 1, 8, 8, 7, 6, 1}
      }    *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `NMaximize`.

```
n = 4;
A = Table[Indexed[x, {i, j}], {j, 1, n}, {i, 1, n}];
vars = Flatten[A];
solns = NMaximize[{Det[A], 1 <= vars <= n, vars ∈ Integers, 
    Plus @@ vars == n*Plus @@ Range[n], Times @@ vars == (n!)^n}, 
   vars][[2]]
A /. solns
A /. solns // Transpose
```

> `{{3, 4, 1, 2}, {3, 1, 3, 3}, {1, 4, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 2}}`

> `{{3, 3, 1, 1}, {4, 1, 4, 2}, {1, 3, 2, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 2}}`